# Remove directory based on content of text file, Linux

Tags: linux, shell, directory

I have a directory full of sub-directories that look like this:

```
Track_0000111
Track_0004444
Track_0022222
Track_0333333
Track_5555555
```

I would like to remove certain directories if they are contained within a list in the file "RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt"

The contents of the text file look like this:

```
Track_0000111
Track_0022222
Track_0333333
```

I tried to write a small script to handle this, but it does not seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

    for file in cat RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt; do
        rm -rfv $file
    done
```

Unfortunately this simply removes the text files, rather than the directories.  Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: So was your issue solved with our answers?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot backquotes around your call to cat. Without them, `rm` will simply delete the files `cat` (which probably doesn't exist, but you might not notice because you're using `rm -f`) and `RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt`

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `cat RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt`; do
    rm -rv "$file"
done
```

or, more simply,

```
rm -rv `cat $file`
```

(but this will only work if the directory names don't contain whitespace).

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great.  Ended up moving the directories instead of deleting them, but this general concept was what I needed.  The missing backquotes was key.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need to `for`, for something like this you can do a `while read ...; do ... done < file` just like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read file
    rm -rfv "$file"
done < RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below command,

**Command:**

```
  sed 's/^/"/g' sample.txt | sed 's/$/"/g' | xargs rm -rfv
```

**Description:**

Command will remove files as well as directories mentioned in "sample.txt".

**NOTE:**

- In your case,make sure that "RemoveFromTop6000_reformatted.txt"
  contains only directories name.
- Command will also work if the directories name contains whitespace.